# Calling c++ dll functions returning char* from c#. Cannot use DllImport()

Tags: c#, c++, dll, character-encoding

I have a c++ dll with 2 functions

```
const char* getVersionText1(void);
void        getVersionText2(const char** res);
```

Both function return a string describing the version of the product. First function returns it as const char* (which means it allocates and deal locates it internally) and the second one gets a pointer to char* and just sets it to point to a char* describing the version.

I want to call those functions from C# and display the text.
I cant use [dllimport ...] style since the order of the calling of functions is important. I first call constructor than getVersion and finally the destructor. So dll must be loaded to memory first.

Can you please post the few lines of codes that print the text for both functions.
I am new to C#, so sorry if you find my code problematic
I tried

```
static class NativeMethods{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string dllToLoad);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string procedureName);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);
}
class Program{
    // Define function pointers to entires in DLL
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)] private delegate IntPtr getVersionText1();
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)] private delegate void getVersionText2(IntPtr );
    static void Main(string[] args){
        // Pointers to functions of DLL.
        getVersionText1 f1;
        getVersionText2 f2;
        IntPtr pDll = NativeMethods.LoadLibrary("p:\\my.dll");
        IntPtr pAddressOfFunctionToCall;
        pAddressOfFunctionToCall = NativeMethods.GetProcAddress(pDll, "getVersionText1 ");
        f1 = (getVersionText1)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(pAddressOfFunctionToCall, typeof(getVersionText1));
        pAddressOfFunctionToCall = NativeMethods.GetProcAddress(pDll, "getVersionText2 ");
        f2 = (getVersionText2)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(pAddressOfFunctionToCall, typeof(getVersionText2));

        // Here I don't know what to do. It doesn't work ????
        IntPtr verText = f1();
        String s = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(verText);
        Console.WriteLine(s);   // Doesnt work
        // And how to use the second function. How do I sent a pointer to char* ???
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `getVersionText1` and `getVersionText2` are the actual exported function names? C++ name mangling usually changes your exported names. You can check the exported names with any DLL export viewer.

Comment: I am sure. I wrote the DLL in C++

Comment: You could make a manged C++/CLI wrapper DLL to serve as a communicator between the C++ and the C# code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a way of making your calls.  There may be shorter alternatives that perform the utf8/string conversions automatically.

```
[DllImport("mydll.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr getVersionText1(void);
public string getVersionTextConst()
{
    IntPtr ptr = getVersionText1();
    // assume returned string is utf-8 encoded
    return PtrToStringUtf8(ptr);
}

[DllImport("mydll.dll")]
public static extern void getVersionText2(out IntPtr res);
public string getVersionTextConst()
{
    IntPtr ptr;
    getVersionText2(ptr);
    // assume returned string is utf-8 encoded
    String str = PtrToStringUtf8(ptr);
    // call native DLL function to free ptr
    // if no function exists, pinvoke C runtime's free()
    return str;
}

private static string PtrToStringUtf8(IntPtr ptr) // aPtr is nul-terminated
{
    if (ptr == IntPtr.Zero)
        return "";
    int len = 0;
    while (System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReadByte(ptr, len) != 0)
        len++;
    if (len == 0)
        return "";
    byte[] array = new byte[len];
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptr, array, 0, len);
    return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(array);
}
```

Comment: usage of  getVersionText1() works. Thanks! But I cannot define getVersionText2(IntPtr* res) because the compiler screams that pointers are not allowed to be used in safe context. WTF is safe context??? I have seen that you use 'unsafe' keyword but I am not sure I am allowed to use it since the entire application is safe

Comment: You can enable use of unsafe code from solution explorer -> Properties -> Build -> Allow unsafe code

Comment: I cannot use unsafe since my DLL is embedded in third party app and I cannot force the customer to use unsafe compilation. But the solution is keyword 'out IntPtr' instead of 'IntPtr*'

Comment: @DanielHsH Thanks, your suggestion is much better.  I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 14):

If the C++ library function returns `char*`, C# code will treat it as `IntPtr` and `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi()` will convert it into C# `string`.

```
IntPtr verText = f1();
string s = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(verText);
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need more speed, you also can do an **unsafe read**:

```
unsafe string GetString(IntPtr ptr) => new string((char*)ptr); // local function

IntPtr charPtr = f1();
var s = GetString(charPtr);
```

When you add the `unsafe` method, VS will ask you if you want to allow unsafe code in the project: answer yes. Or manually "project properties/build/allow unsafe code".